# Invoke Click method in DoubleClick method of ListBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, reflection, listbox

I'm trying to invoke the click method of a set of listboxes after doing a specific code for doubleclick.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.Click
    ' Do something 1
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.Click
    ' Do something 2
End Sub

Private Sub ListBoxes_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DoubleClick,
                                                                                                         ListBox2.DoubleClick
    ' Do something for doubleclick

    ' Invoke Click method
    Try
        Dim result As Object = Me.GetType().InvokeMember(sender.name + "_Click",
                                                         BindingFlags.Default Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                                                         Nothing, Nothing, New Object() {sender, Nothing})
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub
```

The result is a "MissingMethodException" exception

```
Method MyProject1.Form1.ListBox1_Click not found
```

But it is there, look vb, it is just there, at the top, can't you see?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't have an answer to your question, but with some rework, you'll get somewhere.

Actuallu, you don't want to raise an event. You want to call the correct logic.

So this is how I solved this (in C#):

```
    private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoSomething1();
    }

    private void DoSomething1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void listBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoSomething2();
    }

    private void DoSomething2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void listBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var listbox = sender as ListBox;

        // some logic to find out which method to call here...
        // DoSomething1();
        // or 
        // DoSomething2()
    }
```

Comment: Agree with your answer, was my first idea.
But the thing is that I've like 50 ListBoxes in the application (increasing over time) and didn't want to implement a huge switch or if with something like 

"
if DirectCast(sender, ListBox).name = ListBox1.name Then
  DoSomething1()
Elseif DirectCast(sender, ListBox).name = ListBox2.name Then
  DoSomething2()
End If
"

Nevertheless, I can name all my DoSomething in a defined format and try my reflection method anyway, I'll let you know if that worked.

Comment: I agree with that. It is overkill if you have a lot of controls. Keep me posted!

Comment: Ok, took me ages to modify each of my listboxes click handlers.
What I did:
(1) moved the code of each listbox1_Click, listbox2_Click, ... in a dedicated function called listbox1Process, listbox2Process, ...
(2) call this function in the event function as in your proposal
(3) use reflexion with InvokeMember(sender.name + "Process"
and it works (I'm almost dead by now)

Answer (score 0):

Final result, based on comment of Natrium:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.Click
    ListBox1Process()
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.Click
    ListBox2Process()
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1Process()
    ' Do something 1
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2Process()
    ' Do something 2
End Sub

Private Sub ListBoxes_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DoubleClick,
                                                                                                      ListBox2.DoubleClick
    ' Do something for doubleclick

    ' Invoke "Click" method
    Try
        Dim result As Object = Me.GetType().InvokeMember(sender.name + "Process",
                                                         BindingFlags.Default Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                                                         Nothing, Me, Nothing)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub
```